# why I get 404 error when trying to access h2-console in Spring Boot?

Tags: java

I am trying to get familiar with Spring Boot security 3.2

I created a simple project like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityFilterChain h2ConsoleSecurityFiterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .securityMatcher("/h2-console/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")))
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    SecurityFilterChain secureSecurityFiterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}
```

But when I try to access `/h2-console` it redirects me to web form to insert my username and password. how should I resolve it? I even used `@Order` but it didn't take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `h2ConsoleSecurityFiterChain` you used `securityMatcher("/h2-console/**")` and according to documentation:

> Allows configuring the HttpSecurity to only be invoked when matching the provided pattern. This method creates a MvcRequestMatcher if Spring MVC is in the classpath or creates an AntPathRequestMatcher if not. If more advanced configuration is necessary, consider using securityMatchers(Customizer) or securityMatcher(RequestMatcher).
> Invoking securityMatcher(String...) will override previous invocations of securityMatcher(String...) (String)}}, securityMatcher(RequestMatcher) ()}, securityMatchers(Customizer) (String)} and securityMatchers() (String)}.

I assume you have Spring MVC in your classpath so it did not work. because it uses `MvcRequestMatcher` I guess changing it to `AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")` should works.